# How to fix "Unexpected error (32801)" when compiling VB 6 program?

Tags: vb6, activex

I have to maintain an old VB 6 ActiveX DLL called by another third-party program for which I have no sources. This DLL works and compiles fine against the API of said program for about 6 years and 3 major versions.

But now when I try to compile the DLL against a new major version the mentioned error occurs. It seems the error occurs before "my" code is called so there´s no use debugging or logging. The only remedy was to compile w/o binary compatibility which is no real option. My Google search turned up quite some people with the same problem but no solution.

Does anybody here know how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like one of the types in the interfaces defined in your new DLL is different from one in the previous DLL. I'm deducing you use types defined in the third party program in your public interfaces of your DLL. It sounds to me like the third party has changed the definition of one of the types but kept the name and GUIDs the same. You could use something like [OLE/COM Object viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en) to check whether that's true. If it is true then you can complain to the publisher of the 3rd party program. Do you have enough political power to succeed?

Bruce McKinney, the guru who wrote [Hardcore Visual Basic 6](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/), ran [into the same issue](http://brucem.mystarband.net/mckinney2.htm) with a structure in a type library, where he changed some of the member types. The only fix he could find was (essentially) to break binary compatibility - and that's after some correspondence with the VB6 compiler team, who he knew fairly well. I don't think anyone else could do better.

Comment: You have deduced right. I checked the old and new version´s IDL. They just differ in quite some helpstring comments and the addition of one new interface. The changes in helpstrings are of no relevance here but what about the new interface. I thought the ADDITION of a new interface wouldn´t break the binary compatibility. If it does I´ll have to call  the mobsters and send them to my favourite 3rd party vendor ;-) ...

Comment: I wouldn't have thought adding an interface would cause any problems. From reading the links it sounds like very subtle changes can cause this problem - like reordering the elements in a type or making apparently innocuous changes to data types.

Comment: Me too - that has to be a VERY subtle change if that´s the cause of the error. No reordering or such, just one new interface. I think the FileSystemObject is an unlikely cause because I have no public types of it in my interface and object creation is by late-binding to avoid such compatibility issues known to be caused by old IE versions and the MS scripting library too. Because this is just a compile-time issue I´ll leave everything unchanged - code compiled against older versions runs fine with the new major version of the calling application. Too much effort to continue here.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figure out how to diagnose VB6 error 32801 in a systemic way.

My theory is When the VB6 compiler is creating a project or binary compatible library, the compiler decompiles the type information from the referenced library. Error 32801 occurs the source code's type information is not the same as the referenced library.

There is a tool called OLEView. This tool can decompile the COM type information into an IDL text. What I do is decompile the referenced library in to IDL and take the last good build of the failing library. Most times it is a build server version but the build does not work on a developer workstation. Decompile the last good build. Use a text comparison tool, like WINMerge, and find the differences between the type libraries. The differences make it easy to track down the problem.

Depending on the difference will determine how to correct. Mitigation can be done by either correcting the reference DLL, or by source code correction, or source code references.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about this error on devx.com that seems to indicate that the problem stemmed from Microsoft's Scripting Runtime (scrrun.dll).

[FileSystemObject compatibility Unexpected error (32810)](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-76280.html)

Does your DLL reference that library?  If so, can you remove the reference (e.g., replace FileSystemObject functionality with intrinsic VB file handling functions and/or API calls).

Comment: The project does not reference the MS library but the FileSystemObject is used via late-binding (CreateObject(...)). Do you really think this could be the cause of the error ? The post you mention above is from the year 2001. My code compiled fine til ~ December 2009 and there were absolute no code changes since then. I double-checked this in our versioning system. The only change is the new major version of the calling application.

Comment: @banzai: Your code can break even if you haven't touched it in years.  If one of its dependencies (e.g., the FileSystemObject) breaks, you can encounter strange errors like this.  Is *your* problem actually related to the FileSystemObject?  I don't know.  Try removing all references to it and see if you still get that error.  To test this, the code doesn't have to work, it just needs to compile, so you could first just comment out whatever you need rather than actually replacing the functionality of the FSO.

Comment: If the description in the question is correct, then I think the problem is caused by the 3rd party API changing its type library in an incorrect way. It looks from the link as if Microsoft once made a similar mistake with the FileSystemObject (if **Matthew Curland** says so, it must be true). Doesn't necessarily mean banzai's problem is caused by the FileSystemObject. It's unlikely that types from the FileSystemObject are included in banzai's public interfaces, but it's extremely likely that types from the 3rd party API are included in the public interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of the files associated with the core project being compiled marked as Read-Only (i.e. not checked out of SourceSafe or similar repository)?

*.exp
*.vbw
*.lib

Comment: All those temporary file types are not under version control. To make sure I "unprotected" everything and tried to compile - same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic
---------------------------
Unexpected error (32810)
---------------------------
OK   Помощ   
---------------------------
```

This the message I was getting trying to reference in VBIDE an old OCX that has been recompiled recently.

After somewhat long research the offending lines of code causing this error appeared to be

```
Property Get MouseActivate() As BookmarkEnum
```

Just changed this to

```
Property Get MouseActivate() As Boolean
```

. . . and the error was gone.

`BookmarkEnum` is an enum from ADO. Our build server is Server 2003 and my dev machine is Win10. The project references ADO 2.8 but apparently this typelib has some differences on Server 2003 vs Win10